# Pivot Chart made on Windows Excel not working on Mac

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, mac, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I've made a Pivot Table / Chart in Excel on Windows 10.
See screenshot below.

I've sent the Excel document to a person who opened it on a Mac (see photo below). When she opens the file on the Mac, there are no filtering buttons on the bottom of the chart and there are no filtering fields on the right side of the worksheet (even though you can see them on Windows).

**Is this a limitation of using Excel on the Mac? Or is it some setting that needs to be fixed? Something else?** Thanks for any insight.

**WINDOWS**
[image]

**MAC**
[image]

Comment: Has it been opened read only on the Mac? What Excel version is running on the Mac? What version on Windows?

Comment: @DavidPostill I wish I could answer your questions, but the end-user is remote and not too savvy w/r/t the Excel (was unable to answer these questions). I was hoping that someone with Mac experience might be able to tell what version/etc. by looking at her screenshot. I'm using Excel 2016 MSO (windows 10) 32-bit.

Comment: Unfortunately without that (and maybe other information) we probably cannot answer your question ...